# iphone sdk - stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone

in my tab bar app where memory is getting low:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  pageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]];
```

The pageText line is causing a crash. If I comment out this line then there is no crash and I don't think it's the pageText NSString at fault.

I think this is on the final instance of the webViewDidFinishLoad and it looks like something is being released before webViewDidFinishLoad is done with it?

or there is no document.body.innerHTML for this webViewDidFinishLoad?

any ideas?

thanks in advance,

ade.

Comment: Also just found out that if I just assign pageText to document.body instead of document.body.innerHTML I get no crash. So it looks like this request has no resulting innerHTML - how can I check for this scenario...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` returns an autoreleased `NSString`. You do not need to use `stringWithFormat:`. Your code does not have a valid format either.

`pageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];`

would correct the format error, however because you are assigning `pageText` you run the risk of a crash later due to the autorelease.

The following is all that is necessary. 
NB: I am assuming that the Javascript is valid....

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [pageText release], pageText = nil;

    pageText = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"] retain];

    if (!pageText)
        // innerHTML was empty
        pageText = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body"] retain];
}
```

Note that the retain is added because you are assigning the `pageText` ivar instead of using a setter. Make sure you add `[pageText release];` in your dealloc to prevent leaks.
Be very careful when trying to access `pageText` elsewhere in your code as it could still be `nil`. *Be defensive*.

Comment: Thanks for not only the solution but the coherent explanation :)